# How to provide path for urlpatterns in Django3?

Tags: python-3.x, django-class-based-views, django-3.0

I'm trying to learn django but the instructor uses django 1.X.X.
So far, I've been able to update stuff to Django 3.X.X to get it working.
But I'm stuck now.

Specifically, in the below urlpatterns code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name='list'),
    path('<int:pk>/',views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name='detail')
]
```

The first path works. The second one doesn't.
When I click on the url nothing happens. No error code, nothing. 
I think there is a problem with the syntax? Is it different for Django3?

I checked the documentation and couldn't find anything wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: This is solved. There is no mistake in the code. The error was in the views.py file.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
path ('',views.index , name='index')
```

For your code:

```
path('',views.SchoolListView,name='list')
```

Answer (score 0):

The second pattern is part of djangos generic view .Generic views abstract common patterns to the point where you don’t even need to write Python code to write an app.

`path('<int:pk>/',views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name='detail')`

Here pk represents primary key. Check if you have data with primary key you are giving in database.

Alternatively if u dont want to use generic method, you can use this

`path('<int:school_id>/‘, views. SchoolListView, name='schoollist')`

, where school_id(it can be other name depending on your model, verify it in db) should be the primary key in database created by django.